# stub vs nssa ospf

Tags: routing, ospf, protocol-theory

If I want to advertise an OSPF default into an NSSA, why does the area need explicit configuration to advertise a default route:

- A Totally Stubby NSSA (advertise a Type 3 summary LSA default route via the `no-summary keyword` on the ABR)
- The ABR / ASBR (advertise a Type 7 LSA default route - `default-information-originate keyword` on the ABR)

This is in contrast with the a stub area where the ABR advertises the Type 3 summary LSA default route without extra config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you need to explicitly inject a default route into a NSSA area is because the external route(s) you are injecting could also be (and often is) a default route.  If you redistribute a default route (for example, a static route) into an NSSA, that would conflict with the type 3 default route from the ABR.  To avoid that problem, the type 3 default route is optional.